# <Button text="go to page 2" onPress={()=>navigation.navigate("page_2")} />

Tags: typescript, react-native, navigation, boilerplate

Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ key: string; params?: never; merge?: boolean; } | { name: never; key?: string; params: never; merge?: boolean; }'.ts(2345)

that happens always when we cant to navigate to anther screen with typescript in react-native an help ?
example of code :

```
<Button text="go to page 1" onPress={()=>navigation.navigate("page_2")} />
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PudHc.png)

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

As the error message suggests try to pass an object containing the "key" property.

```
<Button text="go to page 1" onPress={()=>navigation.navigate({key:"page_2"})} />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { FC } from "react"
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite"
import { ViewStyle } from "react-native"
import { Button, Screen, Text } from "../../components"
 import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native"
// import { useStores } from "../../models"
import { color } from "../../theme"
import { NavigationInjectedProps } from "react-navigation";

const ROOT: ViewStyle = {
  backgroundColor: color.palette.black,
  flex: 1,
}
export interface Page1Props extends NavigationInjectedProps<{}> {
    
} //u should create a interface of props 

export const Page1Screen :FC<Page1Props> = observer(function Page1Screen(props)  {// then use the interface for the functional component
  // Pull in one of our MST stores
  // const { someStore, anotherStore } = useStores()

  // Pull in navigation via hook
  //const navigation = useNavigation()
  return (
    <Screen style={ROOT} preset="scroll">
      <Text preset="header" text="page 1" />
      <Button text="go to page 2" onPress={()=>props.navigation.navigate("page_2")} />
    </Screen>
  )
})
```

Comment: code only answers are not suitable. Please explain how it solves the problem differently from existing answer.